# Intersection between list and first element of list of lists

Tags: python, list, intersection, enumerate

I have two lists:

```
wordlist =  ['A', 'Aani', 'Aaron', 'Aaronic',
             'Aaronical', 'Aaronite', 'Aaronitic',
             'Aaru', 'Ab', 'Ababdeh']
```

and

```
wordlist_compound = [['A','0'], ['Aaronic','1'], ['Key','2'],
                     ['Aaronical','3'], ['Aaronite','4'], ['Yes','5']]
```

I would like to take the intersection of the two words and make a list that contains the word, number combination number in a third list, wordlist_final, so that wordlist_final looks like:

```
[['A','0'], ['Aaronic','1'], ['Aaronical','3'], ['Aaronite','4']]
```

My current code looks like:

```
wordlist_final = []
for index, word in enumerate(wordlist):
    for word_comp in wordlist_compound:
        if word[index] == wordlist_compound[index][0]:
            wordlist_final.append(wordlist_compound[index])
```

But I'm getting a "string index out of range error"

Comment: You would get "string index out of range" when `enumerate` gets to `7, 'Aaru'` and you try to compute `word[index]`. Whatever you think the `index` represents, look again. Also, your code says `for word_comp in wordlist_compound` but never uses `word_comp` in the list. That should be a pretty strong indicator to you that your code is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your output is easily accomplished using a list comprehension:

```
wl=['A', 'Aani', 'Aaron', 'Aaronic', 'Aaronical', 'Aaronite', 'Aaronitic', 'Aaru', 'Ab', 'Ababdeh']
wlc=[['A','0'], ['Aaronic','1'], ['Key','2'], ['Aaronical','3'], ['Aaronite','4'], ['Yes','5']]

print [[word, i] for word,i in wlc if word in wl]    
# [['A', '0'], ['Aaronic', '1'], ['Aaronical', '3'], ['Aaronite', '4']]
```

Alternative LC:

```
print [li for li in wlc if li[0] in wl]
```

If you want a looping structure:

```
wlf = []
for word, i in wlc:
    if word in wl:
        wlf.append([word,i])

print wlf       
# [['A', '0'], ['Aaronic', '1'], ['Aaronical', '3'], ['Aaronite', '4']]
```

Python sequences *usually* don't need to be enumerated to just deal with the objects in the sequence. You *usually* only need to use `enumerate` if there is something about the index or order that is 'data' in addition to the sequence itself.

Here you are taking each element in `wordlist_compound` and testing membership of the word in `wordlist`. No need for enumeration. You also greatly simplify the task if you reverse the loops; loop over `wordlist_compound` rather than looping over `wordlist` in the outer loop as you have it. Your output is a filter of the elements in `wordlist_compound`; which, of course, means you can use `filter` too:

```
print filter(lambda li: li[0] in wl, wlc)
# [['A', '0'], ['Aaronic', '1'], ['Aaronical', '3'], ['Aaronite', '4']]
```

Cheers.

Comment: Very elegant! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
if word[index] == wordlist_compound[index][0]:
```

I believe it has to be

```
if word == wordlist_compound[index][0]:
```

You're getting this exception on the element `'Aaru'`: its index is `7`, and `'Aaru'[7]` doesn't exist.

But this observation won't help you, because your loop contains some logical errors. I would rewrite it like so:

```
for inner_list in wordlist_compound: 
    if inner_list[0] in wordlist: 
        wordlist_final.append(inner_list)
```

Or use list comprehension, as [dawg have shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20597588/885028).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `len(wordlist) > len(wordlist_compound)`, so using the `index` of `wordlist` to index `wordlist_compound` will give index out of bound errors.

Also, as @aga mentioned, should be `if word == wordlist_compound[index][0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the two collections, I'd probably do it like this:

```
word_numbers = dict(wordlist_compound)
wordlist_final = [(word, word_numbers[word]) for word in wordlist if word in word_numbers]
```

If you don't care about the order of the result (or if both lists are in the same order, in this case alphabetical) then you could instead do:

```
words = set(wordlist)
wordlist_final = [p for p in wordlist_compound if p[0] in words]
```

That would be the better option if `wordlist_compound` is likely to be significantly bigger than `wordlist`.

I've just noticed, in both cases I returned a list of tuples whereas you have a list of lists. You can fix that if necessary by changing the `()` to `[]` in my first block of code, or by changing `p for p` to `list(p) for p` in the second.